# The conditional expectation calculation

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I got stuck when trying to solve the integration of the expectation value of the conditional probability distribution which is Normal.
I tried to use integration by parts but I was not able to move on after I set dv=

$$1/\sqrt(2\pi)e^{(-1/2)(y-x)^2}dy$$

I wonder may I understand how to move on?

The formula is:

$$E[Y|X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \times 1/\sqrt(2\pi) e^{(-1/2)(y-x)^2}dy$$

I know the latter part is normal distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $z=y-x$. To evaluate $\int (z+x) e^{-z^{2}/2} \, dz$ split it into two terms. In the first term use the fact that $z e^{-z^{2}/2}$ is the derivative of  $-e^{-z^{2}/2}$. The value of the second term should be clear.

Comment: sorry the second term is $$\int x e^{-(z^2)/2} dz$$ can you explain about this a bit more. Thank you

Comment: $x$ is just a constant. Take it out of the integral.

Comment: I see. Thank you!